# Do not fully understand this interview question

Tags: regex

The questions is to find a phone number in 50,000 HTML pages in a Linux filesystem in a directory labeled /var/website.  Write the script to get a list of file paths to contain phone numbers in the following format: (xxx) xxx-xxxx

Here is how I am thinking of answer it.  Have a front end where the user can enter a URL.  If the URL has a phone number that matches (using regurlar expressions) print out the URL.
I am not realy sure, any ideas

Comment: Did the interviewer specifically say you needed to build a user interface (aka "front end")?

Comment: It specifically says "write a script". The question is extremely simple: use `grep`. If you don't know linux, then you're not going to understand the answer.

Answer (score 12):

I think this is more of a linux based question. You can do something like

`grep -R REGEX FOR PHONE HERE /var/website`

Comment: I'm going to nuke my answer--yours is better.  The regexp, if you want it, is `'\([0-9]{3}\) [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}'`, along with the `-E` flag.

Answer (score 0):

i dont think they want to enter the url, they want you to find all the urls given a phone number.

so i would prompt for a phone number then do something like grep phonenumberregex

Comment: So enter a phone number, search the HTML pages and return the url for the pages where it is found?